# Configuring labels in TensorFlow BinaryCrossentropy loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, cross-entropy

I want to compute cross-entropy loss using [tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy). The documentation has the following example, and specifies that true labels and predicted labels should have the shape `[batch_size]`:

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [0., 0.]]
y_pred = [[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]]

bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
bce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

From the example, it is inferred that each sample's label should be formatted as [probability of belonging to Class 0, probability of belonging to Class 1]. Is it correct? If it is, why `y_true[1]` probabilities do not add up to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of each row as a single example, think of each *element* as a single example. In other words, first example has the label 0 and the model predicted 0.6, the second example has the label 1 and the model predicted 0.4, and so on.

At least this is how TensorFlow computes the crossentropy for the above tensor. So, each row doesn't need to sum up to 1.

You can check the validity of this by using the function `K.binary_crossentropy()` that is used by `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()`.

```
K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

which will return,

```
[[0.9162906 0.9162905]
 [0.5108254 0.9162906]]
```

The `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()` function does a reduction on the last axis of the above output as said in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy#__call__),

> Weighted loss float Tensor. If reduction is NONE, this has shape [batch_size, d0, .. dN-1]; otherwise, it is scalar. (Note dN-1 because all loss functions reduce by 1 dimension, usually axis=-1.)

This is why you, if you execute,

```
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
```

you'd see only two entries as,

```
[0.9162905  0.71355796]
```

Hope this clears it.